# PHP script only return values if executed via command line

Tags: php

I have a php script that execute an external script to perform a task on a linux host, the script utilizes exec php function to run external command as follows:

```
<?php 

$user = "admin";

exec('cloudmonkey " list virtualmachines account=$user"', $outputArray);
echo implode("\n", $outputArray);

 ?>
```

Result when running the script via command line

```
# php cs-functions.php

{
  "count": 1,
  "virtualmachine": [
    {
      "account": "admin",
      "affinitygroup": [],
      "cpunumber": 2,
      "cpuspeed": 1000,
      "created": "2015-04-02T12:11:41-0400",
      "details": {
        "hypervisortoolsversion": "xenserver56"
      } ...etc
```

But when I access the page using a browser, I get a blank screen.

What is the issue here?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Did you looked into the source that you are sure you don't see anything?

Comment: The page is blank when I access it via browser, however the file produce JSON output when executing via command line. logs doesn't display any errors or warning. If I added an echo "string"; to the file, it gets displayed, but the JSON output doesn't

Comment: It's already json_encode'ed. You have to json_decode it.

Comment: Does this really work in CLI? As you do not have double quotes the `'cloudmonkey " list virtualmachines account=$user"'` wouldn't that evaluate to just that, not `'cloudmonkey " list virtualmachines account=admin"'`..?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
exec('cloudmonkey " list virtualmachines account=$user"', $outputArray);
$outputArray = json_decode($outputArray);
foreach ($outputArray as $key => $value){
    echo "$key: $value\n";
};
```

Comment: Although, you will have to expand it a bit to print arrays recursively.